# Cursor position in Eclipse when adding Javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

In Eclipse, there are two places where you can define code templates:

- Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates
- Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates

The latter accepts a variable `${cursor}` in order to place the cursor somewhere useful. The first doesn't support that variable. I assume it's because code style doesn't have anything to do with placing cursors. But I'm not sure about that.

The problem is that it's not possible to define the cursor position when e. g. adding Javadoc. I use fancy keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (with a capital J) in order to have eclipse generate Javadoc. But after that I always have to move the cursor before I can start typing. Is it possible to automate that somewhow? If not I don't get the advantage of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> over `/**` (which also generates correct Javadoc *and* puts (or leaves?) the cursor where it should be).